# How Does ReactJS Handles Rails Active Record Associations

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

I'm iterating over a user's post items. I can lists the items but not their profile based on my relationship:

**Post Model:**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**Profile Model:**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**User Model:**

```
has_many :posts
has_one :profile
```

**PostsController:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :only_current_user, except:[:show, :interest]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @user = User.friendly.find( params[:user_id] )
  end
  [...]
end
```

Index page controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

    respond_to :json

    def index
        @users = User.all
        @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end
   [...]
end
```

Without JS, I get the values with:

```
<% @posts.each do |s| %>
 <%= s.user.profile.business_name %>
 <%= s.post_type %>
 <%= s.<all others> %>
<% end %>
```

Now with React, I can use the *react-rails* gem for this:

```
var Posts = React.createClass({

  render: function() {

    var createItem = (p) => (

    <div className="row">
      {p.post_type}
      {p.foobar}
      {p.user.name} //this does not work
    </div>

    );

    return (
      <div className="panel">
        {this.props.posts.map(createItem)}
      </div>
    );

  }
});
```

**Index.html.erb:**

```
<%= react_component('Posts', { posts: @posts } %>
```

I thought I had the answer but this just spits out all the users when I only want the user with associated post:

```
<%= react_component('Posts', { posts: @posts,
                               users: @users } %>
```

Then I'd add the props in the js but that's not what I want.

There seem to be a clue in my console that I'm trying to figure out:

*"Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of Posts.*

Comment: How are you populating the `@posts` variable in your controller?

Comment: @nbermudezs just updated the post.

Comment: I think you included the wrong action, that's the assignment of `@user`. Are you doing `@posts = @user.posts`?

Comment: Where are you talking? In the pagescontroller?

Comment: Wherever you are doing something like `@posts = ....`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think the warning has anything to do with the issue but just to get rid of it you can add the key prop in the React component like this:

```
var Posts = React.createClass({

  render: function() {

    var createItem = (p) => (

    <div className="row" key={p.id}>
      {p.post_type}
      {p.foobar}
      {p.user.name} //this does not work
    </div>

    );

    return (
      <div className="panel">
        {this.props.posts.map(createItem)}
      </div>
    );

  }
});
```

As for the real issue, please try changing the assignment of `@posts` to something like `@posts = Post.all.includes(:user).as_json(include: { user: { only: [:name] } })`

My guess is that you are just querying the posts. By default `as_json` (the method called when you return json data) does not include associations, therefore you won't get anything on the react side.

Comment: Very useful. Thank you!